# How to unlocalize a component/Page programatically

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

How to unlocalize a component/Page programatically in Tridion.

I am using csClient.UnLocalize();

I am getting error like: No overload for method UnLocalize takes 1 argument.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: I've answered the question but it probably took more time for you to post it on here than it would have taken to check either the API docs, or Object Browser in VS...

Comment: I voted this question down because you really should have checked the API documentation.

Answer (score 5):

According to the error you say you're getting you're not providing enough arguments for the call. A look at the API docs should resolve this, or even checking out the method in Visual Studio's Object Browser...

According to the latter of those two options, which took me moments to check, you need to specify a string representing the URI of the object to unlocalise, and a ReadOptions object. Something like this:

```
csClient.UnLocalize("tcm:1-234", new ReadOptions());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
csClient.UnLocalize(subjectId, new ReadOptions(LoadFlags.None));
```